# Annotation for kafka consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, annotations, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I wanted to listen for messages from kafka topic using C#.

Like in Java there is an annotation @KafkaListener, which when added above a function, listens messages from a topic and then the logic of the function executes.

Example -
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicname", groupId = "groupid")
// function code HERE

Similarly, is there an annotation for the same in C# using Confluent.Kafka

Answer (score 0):

Kafka JVM libraries don't have this annotation, Spring-Kafka does. There is a Spring.NET project, but based on their documentation, no Kafka integration